# Scheduled notification for android

Tags: java, android

How to create scheduled notification without opening the app?
I already made one but it only fires the alarm when the app is opened.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [work manager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager)

You could do something like this:

```
class NotificationWorker(context: Context,
    params: WorkerParameters
) : Worker(context, params) {
    override fun doWork(): Result {
        //Trigger your notification here
        return Result.success()
    }
} 

class App: Application(){
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        val work = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<NotificationWorker>(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .build()
        val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(this)
        workManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
            NotificationWorker::class.java.simpleName,
            ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, 
            work
        )
    }
}
```